# Activator.CreateInstance and Ninject on asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject.web.mvc, .net-reflector

I am trying to use reflection and ninject on the same project. Here is my code :

```
Type type = Type.GetType("MySolution.Project.Web.App_Code.DataClass");
MethodInfo theMethod = type.GetMethod("Events_ListAll");
object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
```

And here is my class that contains that method:

```
 public class DataClass
    {
        private IEventService eventService;
        public DataClass(IEventService eventService)
        {
            this.eventService = eventService;
        }


        public String Events_ListAll()
        {
            List<Event> lstEvents = eventService.GetEvents().ToList<Event>();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

I get an error saying that there is no constructor found. The solution to that would be to ad an empty default constructor, but that wont inject class I want. Is there any workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a concrete instance of `IEventService` to pass as parameter to *ctor* of `DataClass`, like this `Activator.CreateInstance(type, instance);`, so you got many approaches to do that, see 2 of :

### 1st - class has a concrete IEventService

> That class where you doing the reflection has a concrete instance of `IEventService` and then you just pass as *param* to  the *Activator*:

```
public class Foo
{
   public Foo(IEventService eventService)
   {
       Type type = Type.GetType("MySolution.Project.Web.App_Code.DataClass");
       MethodInfo theMethod = type.GetMethod("Events_ListAll");
       object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, eventService);
   }
}
```

### 2nd - Get IKernel implementation of Ninject

> If you are using `NinjectWebCommom` you can just change the **bootstrapper** prop  to **public** and get the kernel like this `NinjectWebCommom.bootstrapper.Kernel.get<IEventService>()`

```
Type type = Type.GetType("MySolution.Project.Web.App_Code.DataClass");
MethodInfo theMethod = type.GetMethod("Events_ListAll");
object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, Kernel.Get<IEventService>());
```